# How to save data to file instead of list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Python 2.7

I have created a simple contact book app that saves the contacts into a list of dictionaries. I want to be able to save the contacts into a .csv, .txt file or something similar. How do I implement this? Is there a Python module that can accomplish this?

```
# Import Collections to use Ordered Dictionary
import collections

# The main class
def main():

    # Creates an empty list of contacts
    contacts = []

    loop = True

    # Create a while loop for the menu that keeps looping for user input until loop = 0
    while loop == True:

        # Prints menu for the user in command line
        print """
        Contact Book App
        a) New Contact
        b) List Contacts
        c) Search Contacts
        d) Delete Contact
        e) Quit
         """

        # Asks for users input from a-e
        userInput = raw_input("Please select an option: ").lower()

        # OPTION 1 : ADD NEW CONTACT
        if userInput == "a":
            contact = collections.OrderedDict()

            contact['name'] = raw_input("Enter name: ")
            contact['phone'] = raw_input("Enter phone: ")
            contact['email'] = raw_input("Enter email: ")

            contacts.append(contact)

            print "Contact Added!"
            # For Debugging Purposes
            # print(contacts)

        # OPTION 2 : LIST ALL CONTACTS
        elif userInput == "b":
            print "Listing Contacts"

            for i in contacts:
                print i
                # Want to display all contacts into a neat table

        # OPTION 3 : SEARCH CONTACTS
        elif userInput == "c":
            print "Searching Contacts"
            search = raw_input("Please enter name: ")
            # Want to be able to search contacts by name, phone number or email

        # OPTION 4 : DELETE A CONTACT
        elif userInput == "d":
            print
            # Want to be able to delete contacts name, phone number or email

        # OPTION 5 : QUIT PROGRAM
        elif userInput == "e":
            print "Quitting Contact Book"
            loop = False
        else:
            print "Invalid Input! Try again."


main()
```

Comment: It sounds like you want *serialization*.  There are many Python modules that accomplish this.  Some include `pickle`/`shelve`, and `json`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module to do this sort of stuff:

```
import json

json.dump(contacts, open('contacts.json', 'w'))
```

The rest depends on the logic of your program. You could start the code with

```
try:
    contacts = json.load(open('contacts.json', 'r'))
except:
    contacts = collections.OrderedDict()
```

and/or set which files are read/written using command line options, user options, etc. etc.

Comment: Isn't this only serialization? Although python's serialization is nearly human readable, it still contains content used by python in deserializing. I think the OP wants a purely human readable file (like csv, txt)

Comment: Thanks, @ylun.ca - have changed it to use [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Comment: Nice! This is much cleaner than my solution. Thanks

Comment: Still gave you an upvote, though - appreciate your comment. It's stuff like that that makes the site better.

Comment: When I add a contact then list the contacts, quit the program and then run the program again and add another contact, the previous contact gets overwritten

Comment: Contacts get saved now but the OrderedDict() stops working. The output for a contact look sort of like this when I print contacts: {u'phone': u'4565558989', u'name': u'Dave', u'email': u'dave@gmail.com'}]

Comment: @cbandara I corrected the initial value; maybe you should erase the file and try again.

Comment: I fixed it by using a for loop for the print function

Answer (score 2):

You can write to a file using the `Pickle` module:

```
import pickle

with open('FILENAME', "a") as f:
    for entry in contacts:
        f.write(contacts[entry]['name'] + ',' + contacts[entry]['phone'] + ',' + contacts[entry]['email'] + '\n'))
```